# If I edit my answer, do commenters get notified?

Tags: support, comments, answers, edits, notifications

#### Scenario:

1. I post an answer to a question.
2. The original poster comments, giving a reason why my answer doesn't solve their issue.
3. I edit my answer to reflect the comment.

#### Question:

Does the commenter (in this case, the asker) get notified of my edit?

Comment: [Search for +notification +edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bnotification+%2Bedit&submit=search).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No; it would lead to too many false positives where the edit doesn't really relate to the commentators. Instead, reply as a comment to the user, i.e.

```
@fred thanks for clarifying; I've updated my answer to cover that
```