# Notify commentator(s) when post edited

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, notifications

[It is known that commentators won't be modified when a post is edited.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103400/259700) As a result, comments with the words "@user Code fixed. See updated post" or similar are very common, and sometimes they may add clutter to the post.

I therefore propose a feature: when a user edits his own post, an additional entry field is to appear under the post, similar to the "Tags" field when you ask a new question. The user can then choose commentator(s) to notify. After the edit is made the chosen commentator(s) will then receive a notification.

This will reduce the work needed to be done to notify a commentator of an edit, and will also reduce the number of obsolete comments, without the need of additional moderation work.

Comment: Very related but not quite a duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c?rq=1

Comment: Related: [this feature request to notify commentor when flagging their comment as obselete/NLN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183753/997587).

Answer (score 5):

I understand your issue, but I don't think that option is the solution.

For larger comment threads, like common on meta, the list of notifications can be very large. Also you don't want a mass-mail function built in like this. (I see more in an 'notify when changed' opt in on the post from the commentator instead of the other way around)

I think the current system works well. If you really need to notify one or a few commentators you can ping them. If not, just leave it. I never felt the urge to notify all commentators on my post.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my proposal. I propose an additional entry field where the user can choose commentator(s) to notify, similar to choosing tags for a question - it isn't a mass-mail function, not all commentators are notified.

Comment: It surely can (and will be) used as that.

Comment: Then what about limiting the number of commentators to be notified to one only?

Comment: "I updated my post, can you remove the downvote now", "and what about this edit", "is it now good".

Comment: @ace then this adds nothing to the existing system, beside a lot of work.

Comment: I just thought it would reduce the number of obsolete comments.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If I understand correctly, you don't enter a message to send to commenters - you just pick which commenters _receive_ a message. The message will be a stock standard system message the editor has no say over: "A post you commented on was edited," or something.

Comment: @doppelgreener This is indeed what I was thinking. Thanks for helping me clarify it.

Comment: I understand, but comments can be community moderated, while this kind of 'edit' notifications are a lot harder to moderate (or there have to be very good thresholds, which makes this feature less usable I think).

Comment: I agree with Patrick Hofman: It should be the other way around.  It's the answerer who needs to opt in, not the questioner to spam...

Comment: @Fabby The user can "spam" anyway, by @ mentioning the earlier commentator in a new comment. This is a proposal where the commentator gets the same sort of notification, but without the additional comment being written

Comment: Indeed, but only one @ per comment.  Not a mass-spam...  ;-)

Comment: @ace: That is why there is a threshold on the comments. Also, posts with a lot of comments are mod-flagged, so they will check what is going on.