# Simplistic way of marking a comment addressed to self as "read", "agreed with", etc

Tags: feature-request, comments

There are cases when I write a comment addressed to me just to say "yes you are right", "thanks, fixed" or "taken into account" etc.

It would be nice to have a simplistic way of doing so without adding a comment - like, have a button against each comment addressed to user pressing which sends a corresponding note to the comment author. Like, instead of saying "agreed", I press the corresponding button near comment and the message shows up ni Inbox and corresponding mark is displayed on the comment in the public.

This would both clean up the comments somewhat and improve the feedback (I would personally like to know that user who I replied to have appreciated the comment).

It is counter-prodctive to add "dismissed" mark because if someone does not agree with something they is expected to express it.

Comment: I am not completely sure that I understand what you propose, but it sounds very much like what I proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252883/255554).

Comment: @wrzlprmft: not talking about moderation in this case, rather about an alternative way of communicating simple responses. Edited, added more specific example.

Comment: I do **not** want to get hundreds, if not thousands, of notifications saying "I agree with your comment". That's what we have comment upvotes for. And it's anonymous, nobody can know who upvoted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree with your comment.

Comment: haha, well played @Insane ;)

Comment: Could someone explain to me, do downvotes mean that community wants to exclude me from metadiscussions?

Comment: A nett downvote simply means more people are thinking that this is not a good idea than are thinking that it is.  Votes should never be taken personally - they should always be a reflection of the question and its content.

Comment: @polygeo: I never take anything personally unless clearly stated so but I thought that downvoting affects reputation and priveleges as a result. Is this true?

Comment: I never get too hung up on reputation and privileges.  I always figure that they just accrue as I ask and answer questions, so I treat them as bonuses.  One place to learn more about Meta Stack Exchange is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work

Answer (score 6):

If you're only worried about your own knowledge of whether you've dealt with the comment you can upvote it. This provides a visual indication, to you, that it's been dealt with.

If you're worried about other users' knowledge of whether you've fixed a potential issue in your post then you shouldn't get to make the determination that you've actually fixed it. That is the job of the person who raised the issue in the first place.

This will get very complicated very quickly. Add your extra comment stating that you've fixed the issue.

If you want to avoid the clutter of extra comments, or you don't want a comment that points out a potential flaw to be read as current, then "nudge" a little when stating that it's fixed to get the other user to delete theirs.

> Hi @blahblahblah, you're right. I've fixed it. I'm going to delete this comment in 24 hours.

Or, if you want to be more explicit

> Hi @blahblahblah, you're right. I've fixed it. Can you delete your comments if you agree and I'll delete this? Thanks!

(or whatever)

If you fix things immediately then the other user will normally still be online and it's relatively easy to arrange comment deletion amicably.

Comment: "If you're worried about other users' knowledge of whether you've fixed a potential issue in your post then you shouldn't get to make the determination that you've actually fixed it. That is the job of the person who raised the issue in the first place." - but does the commenter get notified about changes now? You say that it is the job of reporter but is he notified in ANY way about edits?

Comment: " Add your extra comment stating that you've fixed the issue." - the "simplistic response" is visible to all.

Comment: No, @Pinhollow, [they're not.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246687/179419) Hence the comment. Not sure why the simplistic response is an issue...

Answer (score 3):

Ben makes a good point about long conversations, in which you can respond and delete later (which I've done myself). But I see the whole "quick response" thing as a non-issue. I'm going to try to expand on his first point, about upvoting.

On *many* occasions in "the real world", I have seen comment dialog end with a simple **upvote** [image].

This says the comment is **useful and is appreciated**.

---

Example comment thread:

> John: How could a Mac user do this?
>
> Macy: Simply use the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> button instead of <kbd>Control</kbd>

There is no reason for John to respond to Macy to say "Thank you, it is appreciated". Just upvote Macy's comment.