# Add tag needed [opendatabase]

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request, tags

For all these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opendatabase+%5Bjavascript%5D

I think we need to add the [opendatabase](/questions/tagged/opendatabase) tag (and/or [html5](/questions/tagged/html5))

This will make it easier for people to find questions dealing with the `openDatabase()` feature in HTML5.

I would do it myself, but that might cause the unnecessary bumping of old questions.

Comment: I hereby endorse this event and/or product.

Comment: this tag already exists, so I don't know why you're flagging and bountying. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opendatabase

Comment: @JeffAtwood I **know** it exists. **I** created it (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7191761/revisions). I just don't want to bump a bunch of old questions for no reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to "automatically" add a tag to posts. So the only way to do this is via editing.

I don't really think the tag is that essential, honestly, so I'd say just add it (via standard editing) to the 10 most recent / best questions that are examples and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Go right ahead and edit them as you're able. I suggest doing ~10 at a time, to avoid fatigue...

But really, don't worry too much about *bumping* on Stack Overflow; if you're taking your time and addressing any other issues with the tags (or perhaps even the titles...) while editing, you shouldn't be able to flood the main page for long. Remember, [bumping is a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page/23242#23242)!