# Let experienced users silently edit their posts

Tags: discussion, edits, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)

How feasible and desirable would it be to allow users with some minimal rep—say, 2K?  5K?—to edit **their own** posts *without* bumping them?

Often times after reading and responding to a comment on an hour-old answer I'll, being an anal retentive person, re-read my post and correct some defective some grammar or punctuation.  Before clicking the save button I sometimes get a queasy feeling that the eyes of the internet are upon me, judging me as a dirty little rep whore for bumping an old post to get some new eyes on it.

How much sense would it make to put in a little check box allowing you to make the edit "silently"—without bumping?

I know there are some odd edge cases where users can potentially write inappropriate things in their own stale posts and then save them without anyone seeing, but surely requiring at least 2K rep would ameliorate that?

Comment: `surely requiring at least 2K rep would ameliorate that?` You'd think that, but unfortunately rep is not a guarantee that someone won't do crazy things.

Comment: 3 different schools of thought: 1) Make your edits during offpeak hours so nobody is around to make judgments. 2) Make your edits during peak hours so they rapidly fall off the front page due to other activitiy.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram That's only 2 =)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Both are a moot point on a smaller site that doesn't see a lot of activity.

Comment: @jadarnel27 The third is a school of thought that `3==2` :)

Comment: At least once I've seen a user over 10K vandalize his posts before rage-quitting. They would have taken forever to spot unless they were bumped by the edit.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - non sequitur is a bit strong, isn't it?  Perceptions can be important.  But I recognize the validity of Shog's answer.  I guess I assumed too much about human nature—a rare error for me :)

Comment: I have edited **over 900 questions** in the past two days. Although I feel somewhat weird having bumped 900+ questions, I haven't received any complaints. I would fancy a feature to allow editing without bumping, but the arguments at this page are stronger ;)

Comment: @Adam, nothing *strong* intended by it, but the point remains. If illogical conclusions are drawn from legitimate edits, then that's the other person's hangup, you *should* feel no guilt or uneasiness over it.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - fair enough.

Comment: @RobW It's not that big a deal on SO since the front page functions differently than on other sites. You did bump 900 questions to the top of the active questions list, though. :)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram In my experience on a smaller site, it's rarely an issue that someone will go through and edit a ton of their own posts. Most edits happen as part of an effort to clean up some part of the site and moderators can warn the editor if they do too much at a time. The whole "flooding the front page" thing is annoying and in some ways an unfortunate limitation, but on the flip side, throttling the number of edits one can do in a short amount of time before they overtake the front page also helps increase the chances that those edits get reviewed.

Comment: @RobW Which feature? SO's front page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> surely requiring at least 2K rep would ameliorate that?

Oh, how I wish that was true...

Here's a scenario I've seen entirely too often: someone says something mean to Ye Olde User, YOU decides that any site on which he might be criticized without due respect isn't the site for him OR HIS AWESOME POSTS, and embarks on a campaign to "remove" them by editing out the text and replacing it with something unhelpful ("screw you guys, I'm going home").

This usually gets caught sooner or later, someone notifies a moderator, the user gets suspended to cool down a bit, and his edits get rolled back. Everyone feels sad and dirty. Life goes on, minus the time wasted by insta-drama-queen...

Disabling bumping means making this harder to detect. Making it harder to detect means more posts vandalized. More vandalized posts, more wasted time cleaning up.

Comment: +1 - ok.  I was wrong.  So you mods really get to see a lot of ugly crap, eh?

Comment: poor [YOU](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you)

Comment: Yikes.  I had never even considered this case.  Gross.

Comment: @Yoda - is there a meme there that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: No reference to ol' SMark intended!