# Should questions with accepted answers be bumped when edited?

Tags: discussion

Just as the title states, do you think it is *really* necessary to bump questions that already have accepted answers — do you think it's worth shuffling the other questions on top down?

As food for thought, what if there was a checkbox that allowed you to choose whether or not to let it be bumped to main page after the question was answered?

Comment: What if a question is edited to introduce spam or otherwise vandalize it?

Comment: Questions are already bumped to the main page by default for any edit.

Comment: Sure. You're proposing not bumping edited questions under certain conditions. How would you handle vandalisms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)

Comment: This question is different in that it targets a specific variant of that scenario.  I'm sure closing this question as a duplicate will only provoke reincarnations of the same one later.

Comment: ["I feel this may be inappropriate if there is already an accepted answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page) - seems awfully similar (and it being closed as a duplicate doesn't mean it's gone, but it does open the door for it to be deleted).

Comment: @Dukeling closing as a dupe rather shuts that door you mention; as an example, dupes are excluded from [auto-deletion by roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773)

Comment: @gnat I was actually referring to manual deletion (people have been known to delete some really useful stuff, so a 0 score duplicate probably isn't too safe - unless Meta users are different from [so] users).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any action that can cause defacement of a post, or otherwise degrade the quality of the post, merits bumping so that the community can double-check it, and roll it back if the edit is invalid.  That pretty much means bumping for all edits under all circumstances.

Comment: Hmm, that thought hadn't crossed my mind...